# Where can I find code to integrate Twitter into my site?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, twitter

I learn from examples.  I need to integrate twitter into my site in such a way that **users communicate with the server via direct messages to my twitter account**.  It is almost as if Twitter functions as a command line.  The nearest approximation for what I am trying to do is like [Tipr](http://tipr.mobi/twitter.php) or Remember the Milk.  I'm looking for a complete example site; similar to the extremely simple example sites that sometimes come with O'Reilly books.

A hypothetical example: userJoe registered on my site via Twitter. He DMs CoolSiteBot. My actual server monitors CoolSiteBot's DM feed. userJoe's DM is parsed, code runs, and the server sends a DM from CoolSiteBot in reply.

Like Tipr, the text of the DM is parsed, a calculation is performed, and the result is sent in a reply DM.

Currently, my site is PHP/MySQL, but I can rework stuff if I can get a hold of example code that does what I'm looking for.  Something that takes advantage of the Zend Framework might be nice.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I have found something close to what I'm looking for: [Remind Me About](http://remindmeabout.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [openid facebook and twitter authentication in Zend Framework](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.com/2011/02/example-of-openid-facebook-and-twitter.html)